# Prove that the image of the linear transformation is a linear subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am given to matrices B and C of sizes l × m and m × n respectively, and the linear systems of the form: (BC)x = Bb.
I am asked to prove that the image of the linear transformation T(BC) associated with the matrix BC is a linear subspace of the image of the linear transformation TB associated with B. 
So far, I understand that I first have to calculate the entries of BC. But since they are not specific values, I'll leave it as incognites. What I don't understand is how BC can be a subspace of B itself.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: As the above comment mentioned, add your efforts and the question looks interesting to me

Comment: Okey, changes were made, sorry I'm new in this.

Comment: @andreacervantes It is also a very good idea to use TeX when typing math symbols.

Comment: @caffeinemachine how can I do that ?

Comment: @andreacervantes Try [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Feel free to ask if you have any questions!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to compute the entries of any matrices.  Indeed, as you have noted, you can't.  We have $$
\begin{align}
TB&:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\\
TC&:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m
\end{align}
$$ 
so $TBC$ will map the image of $TC$ into the image of $TB$.  A similar fact is true of the composition of any two functions.  What is special here is that $TB$ and $TC$ are linear transformations.  What you need to show is that the image of a linear transformation is a vector space.

In the special case in your problem, this means that the image of $TBC$ is either all of $\mathbb{R}$ or the trivial space consisting only of $0$, but it just as easy to prove the general fact.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist No, I meant $TC.$  Later on, I started writing $B$ and $C$ when I meant $TB$ and $TC$,  but I think I've fixed things now.

Comment: Aha. Thanks for the clarification!